# Overriding setter on var

Tags: scala

A tiny question with hopefully a tiny answer:

I have a `var` in my class that needs to trigger some kind of update whenever it is set. I know that a `var` implicitly gets two methods with it, a getter and a setter. Is it possible to somehow override the setter method to make sure the update is triggered, without getting recursive? I mean

```
def a_=(x: Any) = { a = x; update }
```

Will probably be an infinite recursion, right?

The `var` is only set outside the class and read only inside the class, maybe that helps.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Can you use another var as a proxy to a? Read it in the getter for a, set in the setter for a  (and call `update`), and the outside world cannot tell the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will never be an infinite recursion because it won't compile. Due to implicit creation of a Getter and a Setter by the compiler you can't create such methods twice. I don't know if there is a reason why the compiler does not check if a Getter or a Setter exists and only if there are no such methods it create ones.

You can avoid this problem by renaming the private variable:

```
class X(private var _i: Int) {
  def i = _i
  def i_=(i: Int) {
    println(i)
    _i = i
  }
}
```

These methods have the same signature as the methods generated by the compiler.

If the `update` method has only be called once you can do this inside the companion object:

```
object X {
  def apply(i: Int) = {
    update
    new X(i)
  }
}
class X(i: Int)
```

Is there a reason why you don't prefer an immutable object? If no, you can copy the old one and set a new value at the same time:

```
case class X(i: Int, j: Int)
val x1 = X(3, 6)
val x2 = x1.copy(i = 1) // x2 = X(1,6)
```

Comment: No, I need a mutable state here, it is a member `var` of a swing component. I will probably go for the proxy method here, the only solution I can see. But it is so... inelegant. There is a reason why I chose Scala over Java. But thanks for the input.

Comment: @Scán - If it's a `var` of a Swing component, then you're presumably making a child class, which can override the getter and setter methods of the parent; then use `super.i_=(...)` to do the setting in the child class.

Comment: @Rex Kerr - Nope, it is a state for my child - the reason why I used a child class, to have this state. Maybe this can be somehow included in future version of the scala language?