# Transform value on update in Scala case class (e.g. override setter)

Tags: scala

Assuming that I have a Scala case class like the following:

```
case class Item(
  roundedValue: Double = 0.00)
```

I want to perform the following rounding operation on roundedValue every time the variable is updated:

```
roundedValue = math.round(roundedValue*100)*0.01
```

In other languages I would just override the setter for roundedValue, but it appears that I cannot override the setter for a case class variable or it won't compile.

One solution I have seen is to rename roundedValue to _roundedValue and make it private, and then add public methods to simulate getter and setter (with rounding logic): [Overriding setter on var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986345/overriding-setter-on-var)

However this makes constructor usage pretty awkward for the case class when using named parameters.  Is there any other way to do this, or is this a limitation of case classes in Scala?

Comment: First of all case classes are immutable by default, thus don't have setters.

Comment: Well that makes sense, considering I get a "reassignment to val" compilation error when I try to actually do this.

Comment: By default roundedValue is a val in a case class. However, you could declare the case class as: case class Item(var roundedValue: Double = 0.00) and the variable will be mutable.

Comment: Thanks @jcern I did not realize that was possible.

Comment: If you need to mutate the state of `Item`, you probably don't want to make it a case class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make it work, I would recommend keeping your case class immutable, but making a "copy" method that does your mutations on a new instance.

```
case class Item(roundedValue: Double = 0.0) {
  def withValue(newValue: Double) = Item(math.round(newValue*100)*0.01)
}
```

You may also/instead want to have a similar method in the companion object:

```
object Item {
  def withValue(value: Double) = Item(math.round(roundedValue*100)*0.01)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan. After learning more about Scala I agree with your assessment that case class properties should generally be kept immutable (the default). Since the premise of my question was flawed, I am accepting this answer on the basis that mutating copies is a reasonable approach to accomplish this rounding within the case class itself / companion object.